# How global variables behave on nested import?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tested modules with nested importing like below.

## a.py

```
var1 = 2
import b
b.var2 = b.var2 + 1
```

## b.py

```
var2 = 5
import a
a.var1 = a.var1 + 1
```

## c.py

```
import b
import a
print(a.var1)
print(b.var2)
```

Regardless of importing order, the printed result of **c.py** was always 3, 6 which means each module is loaded only once.

Can I assume that each module is loaded only once even with nested imports?

Comment: yes... it will only import the first time you call it. if you want to reload the imported function or value you will have to use importlib.reload(packagename)

Comment: "Can I assume that each module is loaded only once even with nested imports?" yes, module imports are cached the first time they are imported.  With circular imports it becomes a little complicated though; see existing answers regarding circular imports in Python